# Any way to obscure password in Windows EXE start-up argument?

Tags: windows, console, command-line-arguments, application-launch

There is a Windows GUI application (call it A from now on) that takes some password as its start-up argument. For example,

```
C:\SomeProgram.exe /usr=homer /pwd=simpson
```

There is an application (call it B from now on) which starts A. A and B are developed by different parties and I am sure that the developers of A are not aware of B.

Now, when A is started by B, if I see the Command Line value of A in Process Explorer, I see that the pwd is obscured with *. For example,

```
`C:\SomeProgram.exe /usr=homer /pwd=*****`
```

But when I put the exact same arguments in the Shortcut Properties, the password part was plainly visible. How is this possible? B seems to be coded with Visual Basic 6. Is there some kind of Windows API or hidden tricks for this?